# Why when create empty array Javascript shows in output [(...)] instead (...)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have problem with my code i have array of objects grouped by waste_id. Now when i add new item to existing invoice_id row everything is okay. But when i need to create new Key (with id of new invoice_id) it create array like [(...)] instead of this (...). Both are array but objects before( I get them from database and groups them in laravell, then sent with json) looks like this (...). Whats the difference?

```
addReceipts() {
    $('.mass-checkbox__checkbox .custom-control-input').each((index, checkbox) => {
        let thisComponent = this;
        if ($(checkbox)[0].checked === true) {
            if (this.invoice.allReceipts[thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index].waste_type_id] !== undefined) {
                if (this.invoice.allReceipts[thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index].waste_type_id].some(function(obj) {
                        return obj.id === thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index].id;
                    })) {
                    console.log("exist");
                    return;
                } else {
                    console.log("no exist");
                    thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index].deal_name = this.invoice.transport_names[thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index].deal_id];
                    thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index]._rowVariant = "warning";
                    this.invoice.allReceipts[thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index].waste_type_id].push(thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index]);

                }
            } else {
//problem starts here when i try create new arry
                console.log("New!");
                 this.invoice.allReceipts[thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index].waste_type_id] = new Array();
           this.invoice.allReceipts[thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index].waste_type_id].push(thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index]);
            }

            console.log("Invoice:");
            console.log(this.invoice);
        }
    });
},
```

[image: Output1]

----------------- Same:

[image]

So main problem is that Vue won't show/update Third item (new One). Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting/assigning an Array element directly which can not be detected by the Vue's reactivity mechanism. You should either use `allReceipts.splice(idx, 1, newValue)` if it is an array or `this.$set(allReceipts, key, newValue)` if it is an object.

Also take a look at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection and especially at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats

Comment: So i try this but it throw error: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: thisComponent.invoice.allReceipts.splice is not a function

Comment: ```thisComponent.invoice.allReceipts.splice(thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index].waste_type_ids, 1, thisComponent.gridReceiptItems[index]);  ```

Comment: i think it becouse allReceipts is object not array?

Comment: Ah, then you will have to use `this.$set(object, key, value)` syntax. Take a look at the link I provided.